# TypeError: "setting getter-only property "value"

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript

Im trying update the input value but it returns this error:
***TypeError: "setting getter-only property "value"***
I created a function in angular for try modify the value:

```
modifyValue(searchCenter, centerId){
    searchCenter.value = centerId._id;
  }
```

centerId is the value that i want to asignate to input value.

And this is the html:

```
<p>
      <label>Search a center</label>
      <input type="text" name="searchCenter" class="form-control" #searchCenter='ngModel' [(ngModel)]="term" [(ngModel)]="user.center" required/>

    </p>

   <div class="center panel panel-default"  *ngFor="let center of centers | filter:term">
      <div class="panel-body">

          <button (click)="modifyValue(searchCenter, center)" type="button" class="centers-button">{{center.name}}, {{center.community}},
          {{center.municipality}}</button>

      </div
```

>

Comment: `#searchCenter` if of type `NgModel`. You probably want to have simply `#searchCenter` (without the `="ngModel"` part) within your input. Also having two `[(ngModel)]` seems... abnormal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

You are trying to set the `value` property of `string` object which is wrong. string doesn't have any property called `value`.

### Fix

You might be trying to set the value of `term`. You have two option to do so -

> 1. First change

Change in html

```
#searchCenter='ngModel'
```

to

```
#searchCenter
```

> 2.Second option is change in the ts file

```
modifyValue(searchCenter, centerId){
    this.term = centerId._id;
  }
```